# Обновление ListView после удаления item

Tags: java, android, база-данных, listview, android-fragment

Здравствуйте. Никак не получается обновить `ListView.`

Он находится во фрагментах.

При добавлении записи все отлично, `ListView` обновляется.

Но после удаления приходится листать фрагменты влево, вправо, чтобы удаленные записи пропали.

Надеюсь тут достаточно информации...

помогите пожалуйста!

Программист я так себе... Не ругайте сильно если че...

```
int currentPosition;
ListView lvSimple;
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, null);
Cursor c;

static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        currentPosition = page;
        PageFragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
        pageFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return pageFragment;
    }

public void populateListView(int i) {
        c = myDB.getMonthRows();
        switch (i){
            case 0:
                c = myDB.getMonthRows();
                Log.d("ME", "0 block");
                break;
            case 1:
                Log.d("ME", "1 block");
                c = myDB.getAllRows();
                break;
            case 2:
                c = myDB.getMonthRows();
                Log.d("ME", "2 block");
                break;
            case 3:
                c = myDB.getMonthRows();
                Log.d("ME", "3 block");
                break;
        }
        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]{DBAdapter.KEY_DATE, DBAdapter.KEY_AREA, DBAdapter.KEY_PASSENGER};
        int[] toViewsID = new int[]{R.id.tvItemDate, R.id.tvItemArea, R.id.tvItemPassenger};
        SimpleCursorAdapter myC = new SimpleCursorAdapter(view.getContext(), R.layout.item, c, fromFieldNames, toViewsID, 0);
        myC.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
                if (columnIndex == 1) {
                    String createDate = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    textView = (TextView) view;
                    textView.setText(dateFormat(createDate));
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        if(c!=null){
            c.requery();
        }
        lvSimple = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lvSimple);
        myC.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lvSimple.setAdapter(myC);
        lvSimple.invalidateViews();
        registerForContextMenu(lvSimple);
    }

@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, CM_DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.delete_record);
    }

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == CM_DELETE_ID) {
            // получаем из пункта контекстного меню данные по пункту списка
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
            // извлекаем id записи и удаляем соответствующую запись в БД
            myDB.deleteRow(acmi.id);
            myC.notifyDataSetChanged();
            populateListView(currentPosition);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Пересоздавать адаптер не нужно. Т.е. вызов `populateListView()` лишний. `notifyDataSetChanged()` достаточно для обновления списка.
2. Смысла в вызове `invalidateViews()` нет. Этот метод предназначен для  обновления вьюшек, может быть вызван если меняются сами view (например, при переходе в action mode решите поменять фон или шрифты, отступы и т.д.), а не данные. Остальное правильное поведение при изменении данных осуществляется через `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

В общем много лишнего, но даже решив проблему с обновлением, все равно придется переписывать. А именно, касаемо `requery` и прочего кода в олдскульном стиле, то правильная работа с курсорами и адаптерами нынче реализуется через Loader'ы (см. [статья на StartAndroid'е](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/278-urok-136-cursorloader.html)). В частности комментарий к устаревшему методу `requery` говорит, что правильно пересоздавать курсор (в другом потоке) и вызывать `adapter.changeCursor(newCursor)`. Выполняя `requery` (а изначально получив и передав в адаптер курсор) в основном потоке, вы можете получить ANR (скорее всего на новых api оно скоро просто не будет собираться)... Loader'ы помогают с этим делом.